# Removing PowerCLI list truncation

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I have the following snippet

```
Get-VM | select name, @{ Name = "IP Addresses"; Expression = { $_.Guest.IPAddress }} | Format-List
```

This outputs a fantastic list of servers and IP addresses however i notice some iPV6 addresses are truncated.

```
Name         : eg.example.com
IP Addresses : {192.168.100.18, 2a03:2658:1068:0:250:56ff:feaf:593f, fe80::2504:56ff:feaf:593f, 192.168.100.1...}
```

How can I expand this to output all address space?  I have tried using      `-ExpandProperty` but this seems to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the elements of the list to a string:

```
... | select name, @{n='IP Addresses';e={$_.Guest.IPAddress -join ', '}} | ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The data is there but PowerShell has truncated it on screen by only showing you the first 4 elements in the `IP Addresses` property array. If you want to leave the property as an array you could change the [preference variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/hh847796.aspx) for `$FormatEnumerationLimit`. By default it is 4.

```
$FormatEnumerationLimit = -1
```

That will force it to display the entire array on screen. It would be a good idea to save the value before you change it in case you need to reverse.

```
$savedValue = $FormatEnumerationLimit
```